# SDL_mixer can panning?

Tags: sdl, openal, sdl-mixer

I compared **SDL_mixer** and **openAL**.
I decided to use **SDL_mixer** because it is easy to handle.
**SDL_mixer** is very easy to operate sound effects and BGM.
But does this correspond to **panning** (swinging the sound left and right)?

In addition, some articles have declared that **sdl_mixer** has some problems, but no specific problems were written in that article.
Is there a problem compared to **OpenAL**?

Answer (score 0):

The official reference has proved.
https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_frame.html
Perhaps this is my desired answer.